# Guice Singleton and Constructor Exceptions

Tags: guice, guice-3

I have a @Singleton class that loads some data from a database. The Singleton is loaded during bootstrap, however the constructor throws an exception from the DAO data loading class. I never see this exception, I assuming because Guice's singleton bootstrap loading is swallowing it.  Is there a better way to do this so that I can at least see the stack trace or exception message?  I was hoping not to have to know too much about the class, but maybe once I've marked it with @Singleton, I should know to log the exception before throwing it?

Comment: The exception should eventually show up as part of the `CreationException` thrown from `Guice.createInjector()`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest not having your singleton try to load data from a database in it's constructor. In general, constructors shouldn't do work. Doing work in the constructor makes your code harder to test (because before you call any method on the object you need to construct it). It also will slow down the process if making an injector, and make the injector creation process fragile as subtle changes in your dependency graph will cause initialization to happen in different orders.

One solution is to use the [Guava Service](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ServiceExplained) abstraction. Any work you need to do at startup happens in a Service. The services are bound using `Multibinder.newSetBinder()`.

To do this, your main method assembles the modules, creates the main class, and calls one method on that main class. You would inject a [ServiceManager](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ServiceManager.html) into the main class, and the entry method starts the services.

Here's an example

```
@Singleton
public class MySingleton {
  private final FooDao dao;
  private final List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();

  @Inject
  MySingleton(FooDao dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
  }

  @VisibleForTesting
  void initialize() {
    foos.addAll(dao.getAllFoos());
  }

  private static class StartupService extends AbstractIdleService {
    private final MySingleton singleton;

    @Inject
    StartupService(MySingleton singleton) {
      this.singleton = singleton;
    }

    @Override protected void startUp() {
      singleton.initialize();
    }
  }

  public static class Module extends AbstractModule {

    @Override protected void configure() {
      Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), Service.class)
          .addBinding().to(StartupService.class);
    }
  }
}
```

You can simplify this by creating a reusable `ServiceModule` class that extends `AbstractModule` and adds a `bindService(Class<? extends Service>)` method.

You can simplify this even more if you are willing to make your singleton class extend `AbstractIdleService`, but that would add the methods in the `Service` interface to the public API of your singleton.

Comment: Thanks, this is a helpful idea.  I did want to get rid of the 'work' that was being done in that constructor.